# CSS and Javascripts are not loading when i host application in IIS7

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, iis, iis-7

I am trying to host asp.net application in IIS7. I am using published version of application. when i run it all css and javascripts are not loading. the strange is when i run from visual studio it working fine.

error in browser console like this :  `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

I analyse the issue and come to know that css and js path is not correct. you can see in below image. it is `http://localhost/css/bootstrap.css` but it should be `http://localhost/MICPA1/css/bootstrap.css`

[image: Browser console error.]

I have used bundle for css and js like MVC.

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/commonStyle").Include(
            "~/css/bootstrap.css",
            "~/css/style.css",
            "~/css/datepicker.css"
            ));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/commonJquery").Include(
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/script.js"));
```

I also tried simple `link` tag but it is also not working.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the  IIS,It is not serving Static Content, which you can set up as diplayed in the image

[image]

if you have checked that and it still does not work then what you need to do is 
set the identity of the anonymous authentication to the Application Pool Identity if it is on specific user 
here is an image of where that is.

[image]