# Issue regarding loading css and Js when I am hosting the website in IIS 7 localhost

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

here is my Login master page code, Few Js file and css file I cannot use CDN an d while loading the login page is throw error stating : `'$'is undefined`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Assets/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
     <script src="../Assets/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Assets/lib/perfect-scrollbar/js/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Assets/js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Assets/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Assets/js/Portal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Assets/js/BootstrapValidator.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            //initialize the javascript
            App.init();
        });

    </script>
```

My Path to the files is Project/Assets folder

Things I have tried :

```
<location path="js">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

In the request filtering added file extension .js and .css and Allowed to True.Kindly help

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542893/css-and-javascripts-are-not-loading-when-i-host-application-in-iis7

Comment: @UrvilShah , it worked , Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS and Javascripts are not loading when i host application in IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542893/css-and-javascripts-are-not-loading-when-i-host-application-in-iis7)